# box-shadow not staying at place when scrolling

Tags: html, css

I have a **lightbox**-`div`, which needs to be `position: fixed`. Within the lightbox there is some content, including images. Now it's important that the `box-shadow` **stays at place**, *when the user scrolls down*. Also the `box-shadow` **has to be in front** of the images. 
Tried some `z-index` stuff, but couldn't figure out how to get it work correctly.

Here is my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ftgp8fb0/1/)

```css
#lightbox {
    position: fixed;
    top: 20%;
    left: 20%;
}
div {
    width: 150px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.shadow {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -10px;
    right: -10px;
    bottom: 100%;
    box-shadow: inset 0 10px 10px black, inset 0 -10px 10px black;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<div id="lightbox">
    <div>content
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x250"/>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x250"/>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x250"/>
        <div class="shadow"></div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use a pseudo element for this. I've created one over the `#lightbox` div and given a width of 90% (so it doesn't interfere with the scroll bar)

```css
#lightbox {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20%;
  left: 20%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
div {
  width: 150px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
#lightbox:before{
  position: absolute;
  content:"";
  top: 0;
  left:0;
  height:100%;
  width:90%;
  box-shadow: inset 0 10px 10px black, inset 0 -10px 10px black;
z-index:8;
}
```

```html
<div id="lightbox">
  <div>content
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x250" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x250" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x250" />
    <div class="shadow"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well thanks, but the problem is that I can't scroll the div anymore if I place the cursor inside my content div. The only way is to drag the scrollbar. (At least in FF, where I tested). Does it give a fix for that?